# Bootstrap Checkbox group не работает в проекте mvc 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект на mvc 5, на представление поместил код примера с официальной документации

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

При загрузке стили к кнопкам применяются, но нажатие не отрабатываются, те при клике и при загрузке все checkbox в неактивном состоянии, хотя по коду первый должен быть выбран.

Пробовал через js устанавливать свойство, не работает. Все стили и библиотеки прописаны в _Layout корректно.

Comment: Приведите пример кода где у Вас возникли проблемы. Код из документации работает 100%.